# Returning libconfig class Setting object reference from function

Tags: c++, libconfig

I'm trying to use libconfig library to parse variables from an external configuration file.

On [libconfig](https://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html#The-C_002b_002b-API) site it says: *The class [Config](https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig/blob/master/lib/libconfig.h%2B%2B#L439) represents a configuration, and the class [Setting](https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig/blob/master/lib/libconfig.h%2B%2B#L146) represents a configuration setting. Note that by design, neither of these classes provides a public copy constructor or assignment operator. Therefore, instances of these classes may only be passed between functions via references or pointers.*

I'm having difficulty creating a function that will return a Setting class reference (From my understanding returning reference to local object is frowned upon. But I have no idea how to declare a global reference given limitation above). At the bottom I have attached snippet of my attempt at coding this, however they are not working. I'm new to C++ and currently reading a textbook on it, but I'm still shaky on my handling of reference and pointer. I would appreciate if anyone can shed some light into what I'm doing wrong.

config.cfg

```
A=
{
  min = 3;
}
```

Code

```
libconfig::Setting& GetKey(const char* filename, const char* method)
{
  libconfig::Config cfg;
  cfg.readFile(filename);
  libconfig::Setting &root = cfg.getRoot();
  libconfig::Setting &key = root[method];

  // How can I return key?
}

libconfig::Setting &key = GetKey("config.cfg","A");
key.lookupValue("min",min);
```

Comment: presumably you need to keep `cfg` alive somewhere then the references will remain valid. possibly you should pass `cfg` into `GetKey` rather than opening it every time you call `GetKey`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've tried implementing your suggestion and it worked! Is that because `key` was referencing a (now) global object `cfg` and hence `key` is global as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values returned from the various methods in `libconfig::Config` are references to objects held within the `libconfig::Config` object.

It isn't clear from the documentation how long these references will be valid for but they will certainly be invalid when the `cfg` object is destroyed. They might be invalidated if you make changes to the `cfg` object but that isn't stated in the documentation.

Restructuring your code to the following should work:

```
libconfig::Setting& GetKey(libconfig::Config& cfg, const char* method)
{
  libconfig::Setting &root = cfg.getRoot();
  libconfig::Setting &key = root[method];

  // How can I return key?
}

libconfig::Config cfg;
cfg.readFile("config.cfg");
libconfig::Setting &key = GetKey(cfg,"A");
key.lookupValue("min",min);
```

`cfg` is not not destroyed until after you stop using `key` so you shouldn't get dangling references.